# How to recognize this type of pattern in my data?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I have this question that is just bugging my mind and I can't find an actual solution to it online.
I have a certain pattern I would like to detect in my data, like the example I have in my picture, the surrounded by the yellow rectangle, I would like to know an approach I could use to find these, all I need is direction to what I have to look into or read to solve my problem, I would appreciate it if there is any proposition.
[image]